# Jupyter notebook not recognised even after installing anaconda and notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, package

I installed anaconda in Ubuntu 18.04, then I installed Jupyter notebook using the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
```

And it the notebooks were opening on using command Jupiter notebook , however, then I installed some packages like python3.8-dev and gcc and after installing them, the command Jupiter notebook is no more recognized. I have even tried reinstalling anaoconda and notebook but that doesn't help. And even worse is that command prompt is not even recognizing python as a command though python3 is already installed. How to cure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `jupyter notebook` and not jupiter notebook